# JS print function, why return false?

Tags: javascript

I have found this print function but I don't understand why it returns false. Does someone know the reason for this?

```
$('.print-button').on('click', function() {  
   window.print();  
   return false; // why false?
});
```

Comment: Where was this function "found" ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/Jdxpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done to prevent the browser from executing its default action for the event and to stop the event from propagating to other elements which listen to it.

So if you for example return false in a click event handler for a link, the browser won't open the target address of the link.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the browser would trigger the default handler after the custom one.
Returning false would abort that.

The modern way of doing thiS is to call event.preventDefault().
For reference : https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use e.preventDefault();

Comment: But that does not answer the question, now the question would be why is `e.preventDefault()` required. Besides that, you should explain why it is better to use `e.preventDefault()` and what the difference is because `return false` and `e.preventDefault()` are not equal.